# Como funciona um algoritmo de categorização automática?

Tags: php, algoritmo

Tenho essa dúvida.

Eu já percebi em sites como Yahoo Respostas, que há um reconhecimento da semântica das perguntas e elas são categorizadas automaticamente. Claro, há erros, mas é muito eficaz na maioria das vezes.

Qual método é usado?

Eu já pensei em formas de fazê-lo, mas gostaria de saber de vocês aqui.

Eu pensei em fazer uma contagem de palavras-chave no texto informado, e assim, direcioná-lo à categoria que contenha essas palavras-chave. Seria uma espécie de "pontuação", onde com cada palavra-chave encontrada, soma-se um ponto para a categoria que a contiver, em um campo como "cat_keywords" no banco.

Outra duvida que tenho é sobre os recursos computacionais. Um algoritmo desse tipo não consumiria muitos recursos?

Comment: Acho que o que você procura está relacionado ao estudo de **linguagens naturais**. Veja esse paper do IME: https://www.ime.usp.br/~slago/IA-pln.pdf

Comment: Obrigado. Vou ver.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia resolver de forma fácil criando uma tabela categorias, que seriam as tags, e outra categoria_palavras. Nessa segunda você iria inserir palavras que tem haver com a categoria associada. Dai seria varrer cada palavra... Assim o que foi digitado pode trazer mais de uma categoria ou trazer a categoria que tem mais palavras associadas a ela.

Ex:
categorias:

id - categoria

1 - Ruby

2 - PHP

categorias_palavras:

id - id_categoria - palavra

1 - 1 - Rails

1 - 1 - Sistema

1 - 2 - Laravel

1 - 2 - Sistema

texto:
Quero desenvolver um sistema em Laravel

Por ocorrencia:
Categorias - Ruby e PHP

Por maior quantidade de palavras:
Categorias - PHP

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Existem algumas bibliotecas de linguagem escrita/falada e também estudos que podem ajudar nesta solução. Como para tudo na tecnologia, existem várias formas de chegar no mesmo resultado. Vou apresentar meus exemplos de uso com PHP.

1 - Você pode ter um "top 10" de expressões utilizadas em cada categoria e fazer uma verificação com o que está sendo inserido, para vincular uma categoria. Desta forma mais *simples*, você pode remover expressões curtas (menores do que 3 caracteres) e criar um hash linguístico. Cada linguagem terá o seu.

2 - Estudo léxico. Com o estudo léxico (fala) da linguagem, você chegará em ligações mais precisas. Existem estudos que catalogam as palavras e geram proximidade de sentimento e também as definem como verbo, advérbio, etc. Existe um pequeno número de palavras utilizadas por nós (português) que é pouco mais de 2 mil palavras. Fica fácil criar relacionamentos. Este estudo da PUCRS é o que eu acho mais interessante https://www.inf.pucrs.br/linatural/wordpress/recursos-e-ferramentas/wordnetaffectbr/

3 - Estudo metafônico. Ex: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.metaphone.php

4 - Análise cognitiva. Existe serviços, em nuvem, que proporcionam análises de texto para tomada de decisões. Ex: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

Estas seriam algumas opções.